# Rails Braintree webhook integration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

i'm trying to implement Braintree's webhook capabilities into my rails app but with no success. I have followed every single step in their documentation - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/overview but it still doesn't work.

Here's the code in my webhook controller:

```
class BraintreeWebhookController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  require 'braintree'

  def webhook
    webhook_notification = Braintree::WebhookNotification.parse(
        bt_signature_param,
        bt_payload_param
    )

    #operations here onwards
    #...

    render status: 200
  end

  def get_webhook
    challenge = bt_challenge_param
    challenge_response = Braintree::WebhookNotification.verify(challenge)

    render plain: challenge_response, status: 200
  end

  private
  def bt_signature_param
    return params[:bt_signature]
  end

  def bt_payload_param
    return params[:bt_payload]
  end

  def bt_challenge_param
    return params[:bt_challenge]
  end
end
```

The webhook function is for the HTTP POST request while the get_webhook function is for HTTP GET request. I'm not actually sure what the coding in the get_webhook function does and it's not in Braintree's documentation but I found it in one of a user's sample application on Github.

I have configured the routes as below:

```
post 'braintree/webhook' => 'braintree_webhook#webhook'
get 'braintree/webhook' => 'braintree_webhook#get_webhook'
```

Once i hit the 'Check URL' button in Braintree's webhook control panel, nothing happens except for the error message

> Last delivery unsuccessful. Invalid server response

Any help would be very much appreciated and by the way, my site is SSL encrypted and uses HTTPS protocol, don't know if that affects the webhook operations or not.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm a developer at Braintree.
The “Check URL” functionality is currently not working correctly. A fix has been identified and it should be up and running again soon. You can still configure your webhooks and they'll work normally, you just won't be able to test your endpoint with "Check URL". We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: Thank god, I thought the problem was on my side. Has been working on this the whole day but it's okay :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know this issue is resolved and the Check URL functionality is now working. Feel free to reach out to support (https://support.braintreepayments.com) if you have any additional questions about your integration.

Comment: Thank you Jessica.